# $\sigma, \tau$ are not onto but $\sigma\circ \tau$ onto mapping.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We know that if $\sigma, \tau$ are both onto mappings then $\sigma\circ \tau$ is also onto mapping.

Give an example of two mappings such that $\sigma, \tau$ are not onto mapping, however $\sigma\circ \tau$ is onto mapping. I was sitting and thinking about many hours taking composition of various functions but my efforts were unsuccessful.

**EDIT:** Suppose $\sigma:Y\to Z$ and $\tau:X\to Y$ then $\sigma\circ \tau:X\to Z$. If $\sigma\circ \tau$ is onto mapping then for $z\in Z$ $\exists x\in X$ such that $\sigma\circ \tau(x)=z$ or $\sigma(\tau(x))=z$ and let $\tau(x)=y\in Y$ then we have $\sigma(y)=z$ so we have that $\sigma$ is *onto*. Contradiction.

But an example when $g\circ f$ is onto mapping, but exactly one of them is onto mapping is easy to invent.

1) Let's take $f:\{1,2,3\}\to \{1,2,3,4\}$ and define $f(1)=1,\ f(2)=2,\ f(3)=3$. Let $g:\{1,2,3,4\}\to \{1,2,3\}$ and define $g(1)=1,\ g(2)=2,\ g(3)=g(4)=3$. It's easy to verify that $f$ is not *onto* and $g$ is *onto*. However their composition $g\circ f: \{1,2,3\}\to \{1,2,3\}$ is onto since $g\circ f=\text{id}$.

Right?

Comment: Why do you think there is such an example?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such example. The range of $\sigma\circ\tau$ is a subset of the range of $\sigma$ and if the range of $\sigma$ isn't the entire codomain the so isn't the range of $\sigma\circ\tau$.

However if $\sigma\circ\tau$ is onto only $\sigma:B\to C$ need to be onto, $\tau:A\to B$ can still be non-onto as your example shows. However if $\tau$ is not onto then $\sigma$ can't be injective - you see that by see that the image $\sigma(\tau(A))$  must be $C$ due to surjectivity, but also that $\sigma(B\setminus\tau(A))\subseteq C$ since $B\setminus\tau(A)$ is not empty and disjoint to $\tau(A)$ you have two distinct arguments that must be mapped to the same value by $\sigma$.

Comment: You know after posting this post I have understood that there is not such example. I will edit my answer within few minutes and please take a look.

Comment: I have edited my post. Please take a look

Comment: is my reasoning above correct?